# can't change the Magento Admin Password

Tags: admin-panel, magento2.2.4, password

When I login to the my Magento 2.2.4 site it asking me to change the password when I try to do that and press save Account tab nothing happens.

Please let me know what did should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

hi @Ashok Cabral Tera Computer,

for magento 2 there is more security for password. You can try following command

```
UPDATE admin_user SET `password` = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxYOUR_NEW_PASSWORD', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1') WHERE `username` = 'YOUR_ADMIN_USERNAME';
```

in above command xxxxxxxx - the secret key generated for your Magento installation.

you can find it from

```
/app/etc/env.php

'crypt' => [
        'key' => 'xxxxxxx'
    ],
```

hope this will help.

Best Regards,

Krunal Pathak

Answer (score 1):

Open phpmyadmin select your database and run the below query. your new user name will be admin and password will be test123.

```
UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxtest123', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1') WHERE `username`= 'admin'
```

for more information please refer to the [reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-reset-admin-password/)